# undefined method `to_sym' on nil:NilClass on rubysl/net/http/http.rb caused by Rails Geocoder

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder, rubinius

So I've working on a website on Ruby on Rails that uses the [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem.

Here is my implementation:

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base    
    before_save :geocode
    geocoded_by :address do |usr, geocode_results|
    if geo = geocode_results.first
       usr.latitude  = geo.latitude
       usr.longitude = geo.longitude
       usr.geocode_address = geo.address
    else
      usr.latitude  = nil
      usr.longitude = nil
      usr.geocode_address = nil
    end
end
```

And on production initially it works... But in 2-3 days I'll get an error saying `undefined method to_sym on nil:NilClass.` on any controller action that calls `@user.save`

I investigated further, and here is the stack trace:

```
Stacktrace (most recent call first):   
kernel/delta/kernel.rb:78:in `to_sym (method_missing)'
rubysl/net/http/http.rb:576:in `start'
   key = $1.to_sym
kernel/common/enumerable.rb:217:in `grep'
kernel/bootstrap/array.rb:76:in `each'
kernel/common/enumerable.rb:213:in `grep'
rubysl/net/http/http.rb:575:in `start'
    http.methods.grep(/\A(\w+)=\z/) do |meth|
geocoder/lookups/base.rb:268:in `make_api_request'
    http_client.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: use_ssl?) do |client|
rubysl/timeout/timeout.rb:149:in `timeout'
    yield sec
rubysl/timeout/timeout.rb:168:in `timeout'
     Timeout.timeout(n, e, &block)
geocoder/lookups/base.rb:266:in `make_api_request'
    timeout(configuration.timeout) do
geocoder/lookups/base.rb:218:in `fetch_raw_data'
    response = make_api_request(query)
geocoder/lookups/base.rb:169:in `fetch_data'
    parse_raw_data fetch_raw_data(query)
geocoder/lookups/google.rb:28:in `results'
    return [] unless doc = fetch_data(query)
geocoder/lookups/base.rb:47:in `search'
    results(query).map{ |r|
geocoder/query.rb:11:in `execute'
    lookup.search(text, options)
geocoder.rb:21:in `search'
    query.blank? ? [] : query.execute
geocoder/stores/base.rb:111:in `do_lookup' 
    results = Geocoder.search(query, query_options)
geocoder/stores/active_record.rb:259:in `geocode'
    do_lookup(false) do |o,rs|   active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `make_lambda'
    lambda { |target, _, &blk| target.send filter, &blk }
```

It turns out that [this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http.rb#L577) is the culprit on the `to_sym for nil:NilClass` error - it seems that the `grep` isn't finding anything?

The `Net:HTTP` is being called by Rails Geocoder [here](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/lookups/base.rb#L277).

I suspect its an rbx-2.2.1 issue, so I'm gonna try switching to ruby-2.2.1 and see if it happens in the next couple days. Has this ever happened to anyone?

Edit: If I restart my rails server thread the problem goes away, but will come back in ~1-2 days

Edit: this is the user_controller that caused the issue

```
respond_to do |format| #line 169
    @id = @user.id
    @user.update(user_params) #line 171
    if params[:user][:redirect_to_index].present? or @user.chef?
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
        format.html { redirect_to @user }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    end
end
```

Comment: It's really hard to read that "stacktrace"... maybe you could clean it up?

Comment: Hey, sorry about that - what's the preferred way of showing a stack trace? Maybe I can remove the irrelevant parts

Comment: I dunno - I just can't really tell when one line ends and another begins :P
It looks like it's wrapped the lines.

If you can unwrap  the lines, then just use the clickable "code"  thingie (rather than using < code > tags or >) to make it into code it might be easier to decode :)

Comment: Sure give me a minute to do it

Comment: I've code-ified them... but it still looks like the lines were wrapped before you pasted them in here?  There's intermingled code and stacktrace...

Comment: I'm looking for the part that shows where in your code the error springs from... so we can see if there's anything we can do about it from your perspective (apart from just updating gems to different versions)

Comment: Sure I can add the controller code

Comment: So... can you edit your question and add the relevant part of the users-controller (and show us which lines are 169/171) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82771/discussion-between-cozos-and-taryn-east).

Comment: Sorry - I'm checking this out asynchronously while I'm working... I don't have time for a synchronous chat. What I've asked for should be a part of your original question (relevant code and all ;))

Comment: OOC - what happens if you just remove the block... does it all work? how do the results differ from what you want? (and by "work" I mean "fail to explode", not "do everything you want")

Comment: Hey Taryn, if I remove line #171, the line of code that does @user.update then the controller action will work. I believe that the problem stems from the Geocoder that is triggered by any save or update call on the User model. However, the stack trace indicates a ruby exception that occurs when the Geocoder gem is attempting to establish an HTTP connection to the google maps API. The error occurs here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http.rb#L577.

Comment: so if you remove the block from `geocode_by :address` - does it still explode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by switching from rbx-2.2.1 to ruby-2.2.1. It seems to be caused by some bug between geocoder and rbx-2.2.1 (I think).